# Как за раз вызвать все коллекции в объекте

Tags: javascript

`
let salaries = {
John: 100,
Ann: 160,
Pete: 130
}

let sum = salaries.John + salaries.Ann + salaries.Pete;

console.log(sum);`

Условно есть код для суммирования всех "зарплат". По ходу возник вопрос, можно ли не расписывать все коллекции через точку, а показать, что сейчас мы будем брать из объекта данные и уже после их суммировать? Чтобы на выходе мы получили что-то вроде sum = John + Ann + Pete, вместо того, что выше.

Answer (score 2):

В данном конкретном случаем можно сделать так:

```
let result = Object.values(salaries).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
```

где **[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)**  вернёт массив значений объекта, а с помощью **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** все значения в этом массиве просуммировать